# Is spreading the word of Islam a sunnah?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, dawah

Can we get sunnah from spreading the word about islam, or by guiding someone to Islam?

Comment: Allah convert people not us.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Check out related questions [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16777/does-islam-obligate-us-to-give-daawa), [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/is-dawah-a-type-of-jihaddo-both-have-equal-reward), [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11233/responsibilities-of-common-muslim-in-spreading-islam), [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39008/is-it-enough-to-give-dawah-only-to-not-fully-practicing-muslims-and-not-to-non-m)

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it. @LostInSpace

Comment: Thank you @MBA380 ..

Answer (score 1):

Giving Dawah is definitely the sunnah of the Prophet ﷺ, but its ruling is that it is Fard, i.e. Fard al-Kifayah.

> ولتكن منكم أمة **يدعون إلى الخير** ويأمرون بالمعروف وينهون عن المنكر وأولئك هم المفلحون
>
> And let there be [arising] from you a nation **inviting to [all that is] good**, enjoining what is right and forbidding what is wrong, and those will be the successful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:104](http://quran.com/3/104)</sup>

> قل هذه سبيلي **أدعو إلى الله** على بصيرة أنا **ومن اتبعني** وسبحان الله وما أنا من المشركين
>
> Say, "This is my way; **I invite to Allah** with insight, I and **those who follow me**. And exalted is Allah; and I am not of those who associate others with Him."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:108](http://quran.com/12/108)</sup>